# How to properly match a Python string literal with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

This is part of a class project. I built a scanner using Java that scans Python code. Now I have to compare run times with a Flex implementation of a Python scanner.

So I am trying to match a Python string literal using Flex. I am trying to convert the [string literal specification](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) from the Python docs to a C regular expression.

This is what I have so far:

`[r|u|ur|R|U|UR|Ur|uR|b|B|br|Br|bR|BR]?('(([^\\]|[^\n]|[^'])|\\.)*'|\"(([^\\]|[^\n]|[^'])|\\.)*\"|'''([^\\]|\\.)*'''|\"\"\"([^\\]|\\.)*\"\"\")`

But when I apply it to the following text:

```
r'' lol
r''
```

It matches both lines. I want it to match each `r''` separately and ignore anything outside the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Any source char except "\" or newline or quote" translates to `[^\\\n\']` instead of what I had previously written above, `[^\\]|[^\n]|[^']`.

Found the error with [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/). It has a really helpful regex analysis tool.